# BAM can configure only Analysis Services 2005 or 2008

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-bam

Does anyone know what is the problem? I've tried to deploy an activity and view from XML into BAM and got this trace:

> Deploying Activity... Done.
>   Deploying View... ERROR: The BAM deployment failed.
>   BAM can configure only Analysis Services 2005 or 2008.

I have installed MSSQL Server 2008 r2 and MSSQL Server 2005 Analysis Services ADOMD.NET. 
Analysis Services log on as local system account.

Comment: Some additional information: I've checked that BAM configured correctly and BAM portal is available. Also I can see 2 Databases: BAMPrimaryImport and BAMArchive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing BAMStarSchema and BAMAnalysis.

Open BizTalk Server Configuration, go to the BAM Tools tab, and make sure you have those options configured and deployed.

See [this blog](https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/biztalk-bam-activity-deploy-problem-the-bam-star-schema-database-has-not-been-configured-run-bm-exe-setup-databases-to-configure-the-database/) for some more information on configuring that (related to a different error, but same configuration process).  It's got pretty pictures and everything.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer. It is strange, but I've got same error message even if BAM didn't install.

Answer (score -1):

Try unchecking the RTA in the Excel it will work, because the RTA need the SQL Enterprise edition.  See this Blog for more information : [BAM! Deployment Problem Solved!](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2011/09/bam-deployment-problem-solved/)

Also check whether the Database are mapped correctly in the BizTalk Config,